# JPA: related records are not deleted

Tags: java, jpa

I have a problem with database design

There is an entity **User**

```
public class User implements UserDetails, Serializable {

    // ...

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "MANAGER_ID")
    private Manager manager;

    // ...

}
```

There is a related **Manager** entity associated with a **User** entity

```
public class Manager {

    // ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "manager", orphanRemoval = true)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private List<ExpertAndRequest> requests;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "manager", orphanRemoval = true)
    private User user;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "manager")
    private List<ParticipantRequest> participantRequests;


    // ...

}
```

The ExpertAndRequest entity is a many-to-many link table between the **Manager** and **ParticipantRequest** entity

```
public class ExpertAndRequest implements Serializable {

    // ...

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "managerId", updatable = false, insertable = false, referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Manager manager;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "requestId", updatable = false, insertable = false, referencedColumnName = "id")
    private ParticipantRequest request;

    // ...

}


public class ParticipantRequest {

    // ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "request", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private List<ExpertAndRequest> experts;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "manager_id")
    private Manager manager;

    // ...

}
```

when I delete a Manager

```
this.managerRepository.delete(manager);
this.managerRepository.flush();
```

I expect to have the **ExpertAndRequest** lines deleted with the right **Manager** and the associated **User**. But that doesn't happen and an error appears

```
org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : my.package.name.model.Manager.user -> my.package.name.model.User
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

---

**UPDATE** That's all I do before I delete. Nothing but removal

```
public ManagerApiResult deleteManager(@RequestParam(name = "id") Long id) {
    if(!this.isUserManager()) {
        return null;
    }

    ManagerApiResult res = new ManagerApiResult();

    Manager manager = this.managerRepository.findOne(id);

    if(manager == null) {
        res.errors.add(String.format("Manager id \"%s\" do not exist", id));
        return res;
    }
    this.managerRepository.delete(manager);
    this.managerRepository.flush();
    return res;
}
```

Comment: are you doing the delete within a transaction? have you commited the transaction of saving the entities before deleting?

Comment: @FiloménaPetržlénová no, I'm not doing this in a transaction.

Comment: And repository impl?

Comment: @Antoniossss, what do you mean? do you want to see the repository code?

Answer (score 0):

Exception is self explainatory

Somewhere in your entity graph (user of manager) you have an instance of `User` that have not been `persisted` prior deletion of `manager`

Comment: Is this related to database design?

Comment: User would have to be persisted/fetched first, or removed from manager before deletion.

Comment: Can I make sure that when I delete a **Manager**, the **User** is automatically deleted?

Comment: What do I have to do for this?

Comment: Persist or fetch.

Comment: Where do I have to do this? :)

Comment: prior deletion - somewhere. Or don't add user if you are not going to save him

Comment: I updated my question, added the whole method that I do. There's nothing but removal going on.